# How concurrency works in mongo db when many reads are trying when there is already write lock in action..?

Tags: mongodb

I think mongodb conceptually allows any number of concurrent reads.
But it typically allows only one write at a time.
Now my question is
What will it happen when one write is in progress and many reads are going to hit the server ?

Will the write lock allow reads to happen

OR

reads are supposed to be waiting untill the write activity completes

Thanks in advance Regards,
UDAY

Answer (score 1):

> The mongod process uses a modified reader/writer lock with dynamic yielding on page faults and long operations. Any number of concurrent read operations are allowed, but a write operation can block all other operations.

See documentation for more detail: [How does concurrency work](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+does+concurrency+work)

In brief: write blocked all other operation, but write process can be split into multiple parts between them can process read requests

Comment: This seems hazy to me. `Any number of concurrent read operations are allowed, but a write operation can block all other operations.` But, then you said `write blocked all other operation, but write process can be split into multiple parts between them can process read requests`. With respect, which one is it?